# Textfield in Custom Table View Cell dissappears from initial textfield and appears in other cells textfield upon scrolling

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"inventoryItem";


UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];



if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:15];

}
 UILabel *name = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:1];



NSLog(@"%@", name.text);



cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
return cell;

}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

return inventoryItems.count;
}
```

I realize this is to do with the dequeueReuasableCellWithIdentifier but I am unsure on how to solve this. I have the textfield on storyboard and then I have an action to send all these textfields  with respect to their cells to a database. The code for the textfield is in the IBAction to send the data and am storing. I will add the IBAction code :

```
 - (IBAction)submitCountTapped:(id)sender {


NSMutableDictionary *dic;



if(inventoryItems.count>0){
    NSMutableArray *prods = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    for (int a=0; a<inventoryItems.count; a++) {


        if([inventoryItems[a] objectForKey:@"InventoryID"]!=nil){


            UITableViewCell *cell = [_tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:a inSection:0]];


            UITextField *countTextfield = (UITextField *)[cell viewWithTag:4];

            double countValue = [countTextfield.text doubleValue];

            NSNumber *count = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:countValue];

            dic = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: [self fetchDict:@"CustomerData"][@"User_ID"], @"User_ID", count, @"manual_quantity", inventoryItems[a][@"InventoryID"], @"InventoryID", nil];


            [prods addObject:dic];
        }
    }

    NSDictionary *outerDic = @{@"Data":prods};

    if([self isInternet]){

        [self fetchPostAddress:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://localhost/Backend/webservice/set-inventory-manually.php"] andParameter:[self jsonconvert:outerDic]andIdentifier:@"manualInventory"];


    }
}
```

}

Comment: remember cells are reusing while scrolling. So you should keep (in dictionary or use custom model class) the text entered in textfields when textfielddidendediting. And should set to the cell's text field in cellForRowAtIndexPath function

Comment: Could you provide an example?

Answer (score 0):

Create a Custom `UITableViewCell` class from custom Cell.

In  `tableView: cellForRowAtIndexPath:`

```
ConditionTableViewCell *objCell = (ConditionTableViewCell *) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"conditionCell"];
objCell.countTextfield.text = @"Your text";
return objCell;
```